# Can one pump water without providing an external source of energy?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, pressure

I have a farm situated right beside a canal through which we use to get water for our crops. I am not financially sound to buy an electric motor. The water is 15ft below the ground level. So can anybody suggest me a feasible way to get the water out of it by using air pressure or any simple instrument that helps me out? Here I attached an image for reference[image]

Comment: What is the extension of the farm? And this seems engineering to me.

Comment: How about building a pump that uses wind power?

Comment: @jinawee It's enough for me to get the water out of it through a pipe,furtherly I can carry the water with a bucket.That's why I don't recommend to buy a new motor for it.

Comment: Could you use a pulley and a bucket of water?

Comment: @LoveLearning I appreciate your idea, but I don't know how to build it and we got some mischievous kids who play around will never let it go.

Comment: Instead of carrying the water out of the river in a bucket, could/would you pump it out with your muscles?

Comment: Actually now that I translated 15 ft to SI units I realize that pumping by hand is not a smart idea.

Comment: @LoveLearning yeah its too difficult..

Comment: What about one of those lever pumps that were used for wells before the advent of electricity? Or you could build an aqueduct

Comment: Is there enough flow in the canal that you could build an [*undershot water wheel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_wheel#Undershot_wheel)? or maybe a [*windmill water pump*](http://www.motherearthnews.com/homesteading-and-livestock/windmill-water-pump-zmaz78mjzhin.aspx#axzz2zcmRqxxV)?

Comment: @Joce The edits to the title change the spirit of the question and make it sound like violating conservation of energy.  He wants something that doesn't use electricity, but other external energy sources (air pressure is his example) are ok.

Comment: @Dave well, depends on the meaning you give to "provide". I thought of "using an in situ energy source", but it didn't sound clear enough to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, **anything** which raises water is by definition a machine, and further unless you wish to defy the laws of physics, will require external energy input.  Now, if you want a simple machine,  I'd recommend the Archimedes Screw,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes'_screw .  It's a simple thing to build and operate.[image]

Answer (score 3):

The power of the water stream can be used to pump it up continuously, if it is reliably flowing as on the picture.

Have a look at results in Google from "watermill irrigation" keywords, you get e.g. http://www.panoramio.com/photo/59986317

Maybe then you have to worry about how much work it is compared to your water needs, and would it be worth doing if periodic flooding presents a risk to damage your work (the structure on the left looks like a dyke, doesn't it?).

Alternatively, using muscle power, a lighter system would be a shaduf, in order to get a one bucket at a time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaduf

[image]

Finally, if the structure really is a dyke and your farmland is lower down on the other side, it may be worth to dig a pond on that side, connected to the water stream with a flexible tube above the dyke. Once the tube is filled up with water, the pond will re-fill whenever you pump from it, which will be much easier than from the canal.

Comment: I appreciate your Idea, I am planing to build a water wheel pump.If that fails then I try your methods.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN9iLNHGOYI

Comment: That's the same idea as the "watermill for irrigation", using the power of the stream. However, if you start from an empty hose, then the top of the water wheel will need to be higher than the bank to get water above it, which means that your water wheel needs to be significantly over 15 ft in diameter, probably around 20–25 ft as you want it to be deep enough in the water for the stream to make it turn (this of course depends on the stream velocity, you can try to ask another question if you have all the details of the water wheel and stream and try to work out whether it'll work).

Comment: The other way is to have the hose already full of water and going above the dyke when you start the pump. To achieve this, you can maybe start the pump with the hose on the same side of the dyke, then have a way to close the hose at both ends, bring it across the dyke manually, and connect it again to the pump. A little more of a hassle...! (I assume your land on the other side of the dyke is significantly lower than the dyke, can you confirm?)

Comment: your explanation looks so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be a hydraulic ram, but I'm not sure if you can build it on your own. Another problem is the water flow of the river, but you can have a look at it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_ram

[image]